# Results of a vba function not refreshed

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a spreadsheet for a client to manage his ALM. I developped it under Excel and VBA, request of my client.
One sheet "Data" calculates all the vba functions. If i calculate manually each cell all works fine, but if i run the macro it did not.
Do you have a solution? I can post the entire file if needed, for a better investigation.

At the beginning all the calculation where in excel cell, but i created dedicated function for each table, because the file was too big when saved.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim i, nb_tableaux                  As Integer
    Dim j, lignemax, BarWidth           As Long
    Dim ProgressPercentage              As Double
    Dim echeancier, nomtableau          As String
    Dim ws_data                         As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range

    Me.ProgressLabel.Caption = "Initialisation terminée. "
    Set ws_data = Sheets("Data")
    lignemax = ws_data.Range("DATA").Rows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    nb_tableaux = 17

    For i = 1 To nb_tableaux
        echeancier = tab_Tableaux(i, 0)
        nomtableau = tab_Tableaux(i, 1)
        Me.ProgressLabel.Caption = "En cours : " & echeancier
        ws_data.Range(nomtableau).Calculate
        'With Worksheets("Data")
            For j = 1 To lignemax
                For Each c In ws_data.Range(nomtableau).Rows(j)
                    formulaToCopy = c.Formula
                    c.ClearContents
                    c.Value = formulaToCopy
                    DoEvents
                Next
                Me.ProgressLabel.Caption = "En cours : " & echeancier & ", " & Format(j / lignemax, "0.0%") & " completed"
                Me.Repaint
            Next j
        'End With
        Me.Bar.Width = i * 200 / nb_tableaux
        Me.Bar.Caption = Format(i / nb_tableaux, "0%") & " completed"
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a `DoEvents` in your loop, this means you need the user to do stuff before the macro continues.

Comment: You're turning **on** `screenupdating` and `enableevents` *before* your code, then turning the **off** *after*?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick answers! I am going to make modifications now, and try with your recommandations.

Comment: @user3819867, that's not really what `DoEvents` does. It just makes sure that Excel stays responsive in a quick loop (AFAIK), but indeed it should be used with great care because it can cause unintentional behaviour on the running macro (changing cells, worksheets etc)

Comment: Ensure that `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` is at the end of your subroutine in case you had previously set (via code or manually) calculations to `xlManual`

Comment: @JvdV As far as I know the loop pauses as long as no event is triggered. I use it when I output forms that are filled and they close automatically when you press Submit. I wouldn't dare tell which events are included, but cell change and form control presses are included.

Comment: @user3819867, try the following: `Sub Test > For x = 1 to 1000000 > DoEvents > Debug.Print x > Next > End Sub`. It will run (keep an eye out on the immediate window), but will not "freeze" excel. The user will be able to keep selecting cells and sheets etc.

Comment: Hi again, I made  few modifications, which works for one table, but not for the 16 others. I put the xlmanual and the screeenupdating to the parent sub and delete the DoEvents. Can I post the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after taking into account the recommandations you gave me for my previous answers, the code works better, but still not for some of the ranges.
My issue come from a wrong calculation of a argument in the fonction.
In fact, I use ligne=activecell.row - 8, to get the ligne of the range to calculate. But it works if i do it manually, as the actual cell is activated, but not when i call the function many times, as i can not activate each cell, it will be too long for the spreadsheet.

How can i get ligne calculated, with the correct address of the cell where the function is written?

I hope i am clear enough. Sorry for my English.

Public Function Taux_Mois(ByVal mMois As Range, ByVal sScenario As Range)

```
Dim ligne                           As Long

ligne = ActiveCell.row - 8

Select Case (Range("DATA[Flag]").Cells(ligne).Value = 0) Or (Range("DATA[frequence fixing]").Cells(ligne).Value = 0)
Case True
    Taux_Mois = 0
    Exit Function
Case False
    Dim index_taux  As Integer
    Dim ajust       As Long
    index_taux = CInt(Range("DATA[Indexation ID]").Cells(ligne).Value)

    If index_taux = 1 Then
        ajust = 0
    Else
        Dim ajust1, dernierfixingt0, freqfixing As Integer
        dernierfixingt0 = Range("DATA[Dernier fixing t0]").Cells(ligne).Value
        freqfixing = Range("DATA[frequence fixing]").Cells(ligne).Value
        ajust1 = (Int((mMois.Value - dernierfixingt0) / freqfixing) * freqfixing)
        ajust = Worksheets("Market Data").Range("Taux_" & sScenario.Value).Offset(12 + dernierfixingt0 + ajust1, 1 + index_taux).Value
    End If
    Taux_Mois = Range("DATA[facteur taux (TVA, base)]").Cells(ligne).Value * (ajust + Range("DATA[Spread / Taux]").Cells(ligne).Value / 10000)
    Exit Function
End Select
```

End Function